# How do I read values obtained in a Background step definition written in Class A in other class B step definitions?

Tags: java, rest, cucumber

Image link of code snipped - [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYJmu.png

### Problem:

1. I have a Feature file which has 5 scenarios
2. I have written the step definitions for 2 scenarios in one class A
   and the other 3 scenario's step definition in class B. Have done this to avoid code complexity.
3. I have a background step as well in feature file. And have written the definition for it in Class A. which gets values such as accessToken and Response from user details API which should be used in all the 5 scenario step definitions.
4. Now i want to use the same accessToken and Response in class B.

Need a solution to use the values in class B.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is to share a test context for your multiple step definition files.
In this case, use a World object as described here : https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/state/ and use dependency injection (Pico container or Spring) to inject it to your step definition classes.
You can add whatever data that should be shared among the step definitions in the World object.

```
public class TestWorld {
   private Token accessToken;

   public void setToken(Token accessToken) {
      this.accessToken= accessToken;
   }

   public AccessToken getToken() {
       return this.accessToken;
   }
}
```

which would be used like that in class A :

```
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private TestWorld testWorld;

    @Given("Authorization tokens are generated")
    public void authorizationTokensAreGenerated() {
       ....
       if(testWorld.getAccessToken() == null) {
           testWorld.setAccessToken(....);
       }
    }

    @Given("a step using token")
    public void aStepUsingToken() {
       Token accessToken = testWorld.getAccessToken();
       ....
    }
}
```

and class B :

```
public class B {
    @Autowired
    private TestWorld testWorld;

    @Given("another step using token")
    public void anotherStepUsingToken() {
       Token accessToken = testWorld.getAccessToken();
       ....
    }
}
```